# Importing Emacs Stack Exchange Queries Into Emacs by tags

Tags: web

Is there any plugin already available to import Emacs Stack Exchange Queries Into Emacs, filtered by certain tags.  Like the news reader, read mail packages. Wondering if a package is  already in use to get sx queries into emacs. I got so much time now for the lock-down I plan to tinker with emacs and copy paste from stack exchange smartly.

Comment: What do you mean by "import"? What behavior are you looking for?

Comment: Like I can import news, read mail. I thought if there were tools already in use to get sx queries into emacs and looking into them as I got so much time in this lock down.

Comment: Put all such info in the question. Comments can be removed at any time. Please specify the behavior you want (more detail).

Comment: `sx.el`?  Check the package manager for reading stack exchange from within emacs.